# Range Minimum Query - Clojure

Tags: c#, clojure, rmq

I'm working on a Clojure project that takes as an input an array `a`, and finds the minimum in the range `[i,j]` for each `i`, `j`, in `O(n)` preproccessing, and `O(1)` for each query.
(preproccessing takes `O(n*log(n))`, but by using concurrency (`pmap`) and dividing the array to `n/log n` arrays we can solve this problem in `O(n)`)

So, I choce to represent the array as a vector, and the matrix as vector of vectors.

This is one of the functions in C#:

```
    void build_RMQ_log(int[] a)
    {
        ST = new int[2 * a.Length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * a.Length; i++)
            ST[i] = new int[(int)Math.Log(a.Length, 2)];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            ST[i][0] = i;
            ST[i + a.Length - 1][0]=0;
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < (int)Math.Log(a.Length, 2); j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a[ST[i][j - 1]] <= a[ST[i + (int)Math.Pow(2, j - 1)][j - 1]])
                    ST[i][j] = ST[i][j - 1];
                else
                    ST[i][j] = ST[i + (int)Math.Pow(2, j - 1)][j - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    i
```

And this is how I wrote it in Clojure:

```
    ;build_RMQ_log(int[] a)

    (defn check [row1 row2 arr j]
                  (let [x1 (nth arr (nth row1 j))
                    x2 (nth arr (nth row2 (- j 1)))
                    x3 (nth arr (nth row1 (- j 1)))]

                  (if (<= x1 x2)
                     (assoc row1 j (nth row1 (- j 1)))
                     (assoc row1 j (nth row2 (- j 1))))))

    (defn apply_fn [ST a row r]
    (let [len (count a)
     cnt (/ len (log_ len 2))]
      (loop[ii 0 r 0]
        (if (= ii (- cnt 1))
          ST
         (recur (inc ii) (check row (nth ST (+ r (Math/pow 2 (- ii 1)))) a ii))))))


   (defn build_RMQ_log [a]
     (let [len (count a)
           ST (diag_n_m len (log_ len 2))
           r 0]
     (pmap  (fn [row] (apply_fn (ST a row r))) ST )))
```

First of all, when i try to run it, it shows me this error:

```
    #<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of  args (3) passed to: PersistentVector>
```

besides, The code that I wrote doesn't do what I want, because I dont know how can I change the value of `r` (that represents the row number) if `apply_fn` works in parallel. I.e. like it changes in c#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
```

(`r` is like `i` in the `for`-loop in c#)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Presumably this is the same issues as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261473/rmq-function-implementation I would suggest that you try to implement the function without parallelism first, and then modify it to use `pmap` once you've first got it working properly.

Comment: We've tried, again, got the same error and didn't know how to change the value of "r" !
would appreciate your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand you correctly, you want to pass an incrementing `r` to each call of `apply_fn`. You could try this:

```
(defn build_RMQ_log [a]
  (let [len (count a)
        ST (diag_n_m len (log_ len 2))
        rs (range)]
    (pmap  (fn [row r] (apply_fn (ST a row r))) ST rs)))
```

That is, you're passing two collections to `pmap` where the second collection is an infinite collection of increasing integers (i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`).

Comment: Thanks alot, that solved my second problem.I added the following code:

(defn inc_int_arr [x]
(def m3 []) 
(def x1 (dec x)) 
(loop[i 0] 
(if(and (not(= (def m3 (conj  m3 i)) [])) (= i x1))
m3 (recur (inc i)))))

(defn build_RMQ_log [a]
 (let [len (count a)
 ST (diag_n_m len (log_ len 2))
 r (inc_int_arr len)]
(pmap (fn [row r] (apply_fn (ST a row r)))ST)))
        
This should work, still, it shows me the following error when i try to run build_RMQ_log:

#<IllegalArgumentException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: RMQ$build-RMQ-log$fn>

Comment: Your `pmap` call passes only one argument to the `(fn)` which is expecting two arguments. Also, please stop using `def` inside function definitions.

Comment: Right. Well, Its my First project in Clojure.
Thanks for your help, Hope it works now.